# How do I compare one list against the other in Python?

Tags: python, list

I want to compare list `I1` against `I2` and append elements which are less than or equal to the specific element in `I1`. But I am running into an error. I show the desired output for clarity. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
I1= [1, 4, 5, 8]


I2 = [2, 3, 5, 6]

J = [i for i in I1 if i <= I2]
print(J)
```

The error is

```
in <listcomp>
    J = [i for i in I1 if i <= I2]

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

The desired output is

```
Output=[[],[2,3],[2,3,5],[2,3,5,6]]
```

Comment: `I2` is a list, you can't do `<= I2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I1= [1, 4, 5, 8]
I2 = [2, 3, 5, 6]

J = [[i2 for i2 in I2 if i2 <= i1] for i1 in I1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
[[x for x in I2 if x < y] for y in I1]
```

I use this compact writing because you tried to do the same. But of course, you should write less-pythonesque but more explicit algorithm if you are more confortable with. For example with intermediate functions

For example

```py
def lessThan(ref, I):
   return [x for x in I if x<ref]

J=[lessThan(x, I2) for x in I1]
```